# Callback becomes null after being passed as function parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise

I have 2 functions `funcA` and `funcB`. `funcA` calls `funcB` and
passes a callback. In `funcA` the callback (`cb`) is well-defined, but
`funcB` gets `undefined`.

Here is the code:

```
MyClass.prototype.funcA= function (a) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let cb = (reading) => {
            console.log("Will resolve:" + reading);
            resolve(funcC(reading));
        };

        if (cb) 
            console.log("cb ok");
        else
            console.log("cb ko");

        this.funcB(a, cb);
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.funcB= function (a, callback, c) {
    console.log("funcB");
    console.log("callback: " + callback);
    this.device.send(a, response => {
        console.log("CB ?");
        if (callback) {
            console.log("CB !");
            callback(response);
        }
        else {
            console.log("no callback");
            console.log(callback);
        }
    });

    if (c) {
        funcB([0x00, 0x00]);
    }
};
```

And here is the console output:

```
cb ok
funcB
callback: (reading) => {
            console.log("Will resolve:" + reading);
            resolve(funcC(reading));
        }
CB ?
no callback
undefined
```

Note that in the code base I have other functions that calls `funcB` and `funcB` successfully calls the callback.

Comment: What's the code in `if (c)`? Does it set the `callback` to something falsy maybe? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi `c` is evaluated to false, so the code in `if (c)` never gets executed. I've added the code, you can see that it does not get executed because `funcB` is called only once.

Comment: How is `MyClass` defined and instantiated? What is in `this.device.send`? I ran this code with such MyClass definition and it went ok. `let MyClass = function() {
  this.device = {
    send: function(a,c) {
      c('response');
    }
  }
};` By ok I mean it logged `CB ? CB!`

Comment: @barnski `this.device.send()` is from a library that does hardware IO. Note that `this.device.send()` graciously calls the callback it is given. `MyClass` is a javascript class defined like this: `var MyClass = function(){...}`. But I don't understand how `MyClass` or `this.device.send` do anything that invalidates the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue.

`this.device.send()` does not call the callback it is given, but the callback given in a previous call. As it was not documented I had to go 3 layers down to find the implementation...

So the solution is to call `funcB()` until the callback you want is called.

Comment: Please mark this answer as the accept answer by clicking the checkmark so we know that this question is now done.

Comment: @jfriend00 I still have to wait 23h before I can accept my own answer.